# inside the echo, why the php variable can't be printed with html tag

Tags: php, html, echo

I have a problem printing the dynamic value in the table.
The first photo is the result I want:
[image]

The second photo is the result I got:
[image]
Here is my code:

```
<?php
        if(in some conditions, the table will appears with dynamic vairalbe) { 
         //some logic to get the single value, here let's assume the result is 85.00
         $single = 85.00;
         //here is the table with value
         echo '
         <table class="table table-striped"> 
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th scope="row">Status</th> 
                <th scope="row">Tax</th> 
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                <th scope="row">Single</th>
                <td> {$single} <td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
         ';
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here are the single-quotes. They display almost everything "as-is". (Reference [difference between single and double qoutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php))

If you want the variable to be parsed, you have to use double-quotes instead. (`"`)

**Important:** Don't forget to escape all the other double-quotes you want to be echoed literally.

Example:

```
<?php
echo "
<table class=\"table table-striped\"> 
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope=\"row\">Status</th> 
            <th scope=\"row\">Tax</th> 
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope=\"row\">Single</th>
            <td> {$single} </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
";
?>
```